# Почему не ставится запятая перед И КОГДА в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

**Из Стивенсона:** *"...я был самим собой и
когда, отбросив сдержанность,  предавался  распутству и  когда при свете дня
усердно трудился  на ниве  знания или старался  облегчить чужие страдания  и
несчастья".*

***Перед И КОГДА запятая не стоит, да и не нужна она, это очевидно. Но почему?***

По форме предложение сложноподчинённое с однородными придаточными, по значению сходными с обстоятельствами времени. Может, всё дело в повторяющемся союзе И перед ними? Придаточные просто выполняют функцию однородных обстоятельств?

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Сама я тоже поищу ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь **повторяющийся сочинительный союз И...И.**

При наличии повторяющихся союзов И...И,  НИ...НИ,  ИЛИ...ИЛИ, ТО ЛИ...ТО ЛИ, НЕ ТО...НЕ ТО, двойных союзов КАК...ТАК,НЕ ТОЛЬКО...НО И, а также противопоставления НЕ...А запятые ставятся между придаточными предложениями, **но не ставятся между главной и придаточной частями предложения**

Розенталь  [XXVIII. ЗНАКИ ПРЕПИНАНИЯ В СЛОЖНОПОДЧИНЕННОМ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИИ](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm)

**Примеры:**

Изъяснительные придаточные:  союз КАК, повторяющийся союз И...И:
    Приятно слышать и как стонет вьюга, и как злится за окном тайга.

Изъяснительные придаточные: союзное слово ГДЕ, повторяющийся союз НИ...НИ:
   Я не знал ни где я нахожусь, ни как добраться до ближайшего жилья.

Придаточные времени: союз КОГДА, повторяющийся союз НЕ  ТО...НЕ  ТО:
   Мы потеряли дорогу не то когда свернули на тропинку, не то когда уже вышли из леса.

Он знал не только где можно остановиться, но и сколько берут за ночлег.

Придаточные времени: союз КОГДА, противопоставление НЕ...А:
  В море, в качку, спишь не когда хочешь, а  когда можешь.

Answer (score 3):

Запятая здесь, судя по всему, нужна. Хотя бы одна, скорее всего - вторая. Не знаю почему, но в источниках действительно встречаются разночтения, причем вариант без обеих запятых преобладает. Но объяснить это вариант (без запятых) очень трудно.

Единственное, что могу предположить. При некотором допущении первое "И" можно считать усилительной частицей (или самостоятельным союзом), а второе - обычным одиночным союзом. 
Тогда первое И (частица или союз) исключает первую запятую, в второе уже как обычный союз "съедает" вторую.

> § 33.4 Не ставится запятая между главной и следующей за ней
>   придаточной частью сложноподчиненного предложения в случаях: ... 2)
>   если перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом стоит
>   сочинительный союз и, или, либо и т. д. (обычно повторяющийся): Учтите
>   и что он сказал, и как он это сказал;  Он не слышал  ни как сестра
>   вошла в комнату, ни как потом бесшумно вышла;  Я отвечу на ваш запрос 
>   или когда прибудет очередной номер информационного бюллетеня, или
>   когда сам наведу нужную справку, ср. также при одиночном союзе: Не
>   представлял себе  и как выбраться из создавшегося положения;  Я знаю 
>   и как это делается;  Мальчика прощали  и когда он никого не слушался,
>   но (при обратном порядке главной и придаточной частей): Как звали
>   этого мальчика,  и не припомню;
>
> § 35.3
>
> Между однородными придаточными частями сложноподчиненного предложения,
>   связанными неповторяющимися соединительными или разделительными
>   союзами, запятая не ставится: Отец мой говорил,  что он не видывал
>   таких хлебов и что нынешний год урожай от личный (Акс.); Чудилось, 
>   будто корчуют сразу весь лес и выдираемые из земли корни и сама земля
>   стонут и вопят от боли (Фед.) — повторяющихся союзов здесь нет (первый
>   союз и соединяет две придаточные части, второй — однородные подлежащие
>   корни и земля, третий — однородные сказуемые стонут и вопят);  Что это
>   за соединение и кто такой Ковпак,  мы тогда ещё не знали (Медв.).

(Розенталь)
https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827520.html

Но это уж очень надо исхитриться, чтобы до такой грамматики
додуматься. Так что считаю правильным вариант со второй запятой.

*"...я был самим собой и когда, отбросив сдержанность, предавался распутству, и когда при свете дня усердно трудился на ниве знания или старался облегчить чужие страдания и несчастья"*.

Comment: Насчёт второй запятой совершенно с Вами согласна. Она должна быть однозначно. Благодарю Вас.

Comment: @ЕкатеринаКаштанова Так а вы о какой спрашивали? С первой тут сложнее, надо определиться, что это союз или частица... Но в принципе -  § 33.4 по моей ссылке решает вопрос и для самых замысловатых трактовок.